# Gitignore every subfolder with name or .trash in project

Tags: git

I have project with name of `test` i have these folders into that but i want git not include `.trash` folder. is there any way to do that

```
test/views/.trash
test/views/folder1/partials
test/views/folder2/partials
test/views/folder3/pdf/.trash
test/views/folder4/show/.trash
test/views/folder5/.trash
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [git scm website, regarding gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> A leading `**` followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
> example, `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` anywhere, the same
> as pattern `foo`. `**/foo/bar` matches file or directory `bar`
> anywhere that is directly under directory `foo`.

You gen igonre `trash` folders by this pattern:

```
**/.trash/
```